# AttributeError:partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'cuda'

Tags: python, pytorch

In the `__init__.py` of the module named `torch-sparse`, it is so bizarre and confusing .And `torch.__version__ == 1.8.0` , `torch-sparse == 0.6.11`.

Comment: Can you provide the full error stack trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/anaconda/envs/ml/Lib/site-packages/torch_sparse/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 141, in _load_global_deps
    if platform.system() == 'Windows' or sys.executable == 'torch_deploy':

Comment: File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\platform.py", line 897, in system
    return uname().system
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\platform.py", line 785, in uname
    node = _node()
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\platform.py", line 588, in _node
    import socket
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\socket.py", line 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors

Comment: File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\selectors.py", line 12, in <module>
    import select
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\Lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\select.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torch_sparse.tensor import SparseTensor
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'cuda' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Because the character limit, I have to divide that into 3 parts. Thanks for your help.@Ivan

Comment: Please edit your question with the full stack trace (and remove your comments).